# Gomplate : bad character U+0022 '-'

Tags: go, yaml, gomplate

I was trying out [gomplate](https://docs.gomplate.ca/) and encountered an error.

For context I've defined a template file, test.tmplt, and a datasource file, dev.yaml.
test.tmplt has the following content :

```
localAPIEndpoint:
    advertiseAddress: {{ (datasource "k8s").api-advertise-ip }}
```

while dev.yaml contains the following :

```
api-advertise-ip: 192.168.0.1
```

If I try to fill in the content of test.tmplt using gomplate like so :

```
gomplate -d k8s=./dev.yaml -f ./test.tmplt -o test.conf
```

I get the following error :

```
09:42:44 FTL  error="template: ./test.tmplt:2: bad character U+002D '-'"
```

Seems to me that it does not like the '-' symbol in the template file. Any workaround?Is it the intended behaviour?

Edit 1:
Thanks @icza for the answer which works correctly for the example above. Yet if I modify the yaml file to have nested fields it seems to break down.
For example

dev.yaml :

```
kubernetes:
    api-advertise-ip: 192.168.0.0
```

test.tmplt :

```
localAPIEndpoint:
    advertiseAddress: {{ index (datasource "k8s") "kubernetes.api-advertise-ip" }}
```

In this case the output of :

```
gomplate -d k8s=./dev.yaml -f ./test.tmplt -o test.conf
```

is :

```
localAPIEndpoint:
    advertiseAddress: <no value>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `"k8s"` data source is a YAML config, and you want to access the `api-advertise-ip` property of it.

Since `api-advertise-ip` contains dashes, you can't use the name as-is in the template, because that's a syntax error: the template engine tries to use `api` as the property name, and the dash after that is a syntax error.

You have to put the property name in quotes that contains dashes: `"api-advertise-ip"`, but this using the `.` selector is also invalid syntax.

Use the builtin `index` function to index the YAML datasource with this key:

```
localAPIEndpoint:
    advertiseAddress: {{ index (datasource "k8s") "api-advertise-ip" }}
```

`gomplate` uses [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) under the hood, see a working example on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gkSE-PN-B62).

When using `index` and you have multiple nested levels, provide each key as an additional parameter to `index`.

For example:

```
localAPIEndpoint:
    advertiseAddress: {{ index (datasource "k8s") "kubernetes" "api-advertise-ip" }}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7ONzo5Mx-bL).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried using index while keeping the dot (not familiar with golang) and went nowhere!Thanks for the solution, I'll tryit asap and accept the answer if it works :)

Comment: It works but how about nested fields?For example in my yaml file i might have "kubernetes:\n\tapi-end-point: 123". Using {{ index (datasource "k8s") "kubernetes.api-end-point" }} dosen't work. Well it compiles correctly but the output is "<no value>". How come?

Comment: @MFranc Each key is an additional parameter to `index` like this: `{{ index (datasource "k8s") "kubernetes" "api-end-point" }}`. See a working example on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gpjmia5EwHc).

Answer (score 4):

For those landing here for accessing values from Kubernetes secret (with `kubectl`) whose keys have hyphen `-` in them, the solution as suggested by @icza is:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> \
        get secret <secret-name>  \
        -ogo-template='{{ index .data "key-with-hyphens" | base64decode }}'
```